# Can you be hacked if someone knows your public IP address?

Tags: security, ip

Can I be hacked by someone who knows my IP address?

My guess is Yes, but not easily. Is that right? That would require my ISP's servers to also be attacked to get to me. Also, if it was that simple I'd assume anyone could be randomly hacked at any time.

I have a firewall and a WiFi router which has a built-in firewall. My internet is supplied by an ISP modem/router. I don't know whether that has a firewall.

Comment: If someone knows your street address, can you be burglarized?  If *no-one* knows your street address, can you be burglarized?

Answer (score 3):

Any connection you ever make, to anywhere, for any reason, needs to know your IP address or it cannot talk to you.

This, in itself, is not dangerous - in fact it is essential.

A bad actor could use that information to attempt to penetrate or deny service to your router... which, of course, you are no longer using the default login & password on...*are you?*

> anyone could be randomly hacked at any time...

In fact, there are bots out there right now doing just that, looking for known exploits - routers still using the default login details are a prime candidate for an easy attack.

> That would require my ISP's servers to also be attacked to get to me.

Not at all. They'd have to carry the traffic & might notice a denial of service attack, but not a small probe.